# Block Elements Inside Multicolumn Layout - Padding Issue In Chrome/IE

Tags: css, cross-browser, multiple-columns

### Question Description:

I've got an unordered list of items, using a typical `ul` -> `li` structure. I applied `column-count:3` to this `ul` (along with prefixes). It works beautifully in Firefox. In Chrome and IE11 (where it should work according to [**caniuse**](http://caniuse.com/multicolumn)), it works mostly, but I'm  running into an odd behavior. Take a look at the screenshots:

#### Firefox:

[image]

#### Chrome:

[image]

If you'll notice, the middle column is pushed down in Chrome (IE11 is identical). It appears that in those two cases the browser is attempting to make the first two column equal height. Is there a way to tell it to respect `block` items?

---

### Code:

#### HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>List Item 1</li>
    <li>List Item 2</li>
    ...
    <li>List Item 20</li>
</ul>
```

#### CSS:

```
ul {
    -moz-column-count:3;
    -webkit-column-count:3;
    column-count:3;
}

ul li {
    display:block;
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    border-left:solid 4px rgb(205,88,5);
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
```

---

### Working Example:

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6cVqZ/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On the first JSFiddle, I found adding to the `li`

```css
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;
```

Worked to align the elements and fill the column width.

**Edit:**

The above currently works in both Firefox and Chrome perfectly. On IE, I also have to set the `li` to `box-sizing:border-box;`, because specifying `width` while `padding` is specified causes an overflow otherwise. Link to updated version of the original Fiddle, now working in all major browsers:

http://jsfiddle.net/6cVqZ/40/

Comment: Thank you, this helped me in similar situation where I had similar weird multi-column issues in Chrome.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently specified in the [W3C spec](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-multicol/) on how to handle padding/margin breaking by default. FF seems to be avoiding breaking on the padding box while Chrome/IE are not. To get the intended behavior you're looking for, use `break-inside: avoid`.

Here is a [JSFiddle with working in IE11, FF, and somewhat in Chrome](http://jsfiddle.net/6cVqZ/15/embedded/result/) (Chrome has a minor bug)

Hope that helps!

Comment: I'm guessing that no one was thinking about using block elements inside a wrapper broken into columns. I ended up using a small with of javascript to check how many `li` items there are in the list, and set the `height` of the total wrapper based on that. The performance isn't terrible since I know the height ahead of time of each `li`. I'm going to mark yours as the answer though, because it fixes the problem on IE11, at least, if not Chrome. If you ever notice something changed in Chrome that works, please come back and mention it here. Thanks!

Comment: I did open a bug against them for this, so that at minimum you can hopefully have a work around that doesn't need JS. I'll update this once their bug is fixed or we come to a different interop solution. Thanks!! https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=393966

Comment: I'm switching the answer to Jan vH, because his method of using `inline-block` works in all major browsers at this point, and `break-inside` doesn't appear to have any effect. Thank you for the answer and research though.

Comment: This no longer fixes Chrome (45).  However, if you add **-webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;**, that fixes it.  Here's an updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0zLabxvs/1/).  (If you update your answer, I'll upvote it.)

Answer (score 0):

The padding style on the li is adding extra padding to the bottom of the previous column which overflows into the next column, try:
(http://jsfiddle.net/6cVqZ/1/)

```
ul li {
    display:block;
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:10px 10px 0 10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    border-left:solid 4px rgb(205,88,5);
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
```

The only disadvantage to this is that your text is no longer aligned in the center, to fix this you can add a min-height of say 30px to the li

Comment: Unfortunately, when I add `height` or `min-height`, Chrome displays it the same as with `padding`.

Comment: Did you separate out the padding styles as in the code above (padding: 10px 10px 0 10px)?